# RXJava Observables in Main Activity not being updated when Android app is on another activity

Tags: android, bluetooth, rx-java, rx-java2

My app has a main activity (essentially the home screen) and then other activities like Settings, Bluetooth devices, etc. On the Bluetooth devices activity, I display some real-time data that I want to update on the Main Activity without leaving the Bluetooth devices activity. I'm using RxJava so that I can take advantage of Observables and composite disposables, but currently my Observables on the home screen aren't getting the updates from a Bluetooth device unless I remain on the Main Activity.

I've tried using an Observable:

```
Observable<Heartrate> heartrateObservable;
.
.
.
compositeDisposable.add(heartrateObservable
     .subscribe(heartrate -> {
     // update the heartrate on the main screen
});
```

I would expect that any time I get the updates from on a different screen, that the main activity could do these updates, but that's not what's happening. The value just stays the same until I return to the main activity. Any ideas?

Comment: MainActivity should not be updated while another activity is on the foreground.

Comment: where is heartrateObservable placed? and when is your compositeDisposable being  cleared? probably your compositeDisposable is being cleared on activity pause lifecycle, so the subscription is disposed when the activity is on background..